# Git merge doesn't work after branch was remade

Tags: git

I need some help understanding what is happening.

In our project we have lots of branches, some branches are specific for some tasks, and there are two special branches - 'master' and 'dev', which are constantly checked out and at our production and testing server.

We make all our task branches from 'master' branch. When the task is completed - we merge it to 'dev' branch and check on the testing server if everything works ok. After that we again merge that task branch to 'master' branch and its then uploaded to production server.

At some point yesterday we decided that 'dev' branch was irreparable due to lots of conflicts. And we deleted it. After that we recreated a new 'dev' branch from 'master'.

However, we have a problem now, because some of the branches cannot be merged again into the 'dev' branch. Git displays "already up to date" message when attempting merge, but we can see in the code that the changes are not there.

My question is - what is happening? and how can we solve this?

**EDIT:**

I have since asking this question figured out that probably due to some strange merges - there are now some files missing from the 'master' (!) branch. There is a commit, for example, that adds some file to the 'master' branch. However, a few commits/merges later - it is not there anymore.

I have no idea why everything is happening, we deleted 'dev' branch, but the most affected is 'master' branch. Some branches cannot be merged due to this 'already up to date' error, and some files are missing, as if they were not added at all.

The only thing I found on Internet was back to 2010-2012 topics, discussing how it was possible to erase a part of git history away with some strange merges, so that is the only theory I currently have.

Comment: The branches that you are trying to merge into the new `dev` branch, were they already merged into the `master` branch from which you took out a new `dev` branch or are these new, non-merged branches ?

Comment: They were merged into the old dev, but they were not on master. They should be merging ok, but for some reason - do not.

Comment: For a guess, I would say make all the developers delete their local `dev` branch and also delete the remote `dev` branch. Create a new `dev` branch from `master` and then try the merge.

Comment: You can try `git diff dev...task_branch` or `git diff master...task_branch` and you should see only your expected changes.

Comment: @Toly: what happens when you do a git diff, preferably with SHA-1 sums?

Comment: I have no idea =(( currently I don't have enough time to check again, because I already spent several hours trying to solve this case, so I have to work around it to preserve time. I guess the question becomes theoretical, like in the area of "how on earth could this happen?" or "what could have gone wrong to achieve that result?"

Comment: Since the recreation of the dev branch is performed in the exact way it was created before, there can not be a difference in the result. This leads me to the conclusion, that the mistake must lie in the specific order of commands, which we can not investigate.

Comment: I've added some new info to the question. You are probably right about the order of commands, but I am completely unsure about what is happening.

Comment: @Toly: there is a tool called gource which shows all changes to files in a branch over time. Maybe it helps to figure out how files were lost: http://code.google.com/p/gource/